# Is there any reason not to use DoubleEndedIterator for iterators that don't iterate over a range of things?

Tags: rust

As I understand it, [`DoubleEndedIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.DoubleEndedIterator.html) is meant for iterators that iterate over a range of items and can start at either end. For example, `(1..10)` could implement this to be able to go from 1 to 10, or from 10 to 1. However, I have a situation where it would be useful to use this trait for an iterator that doesn't iterate over a range of things, but instead can go forwards or backwards from the same position, like this:

```
struct ExtremeIterator {
    number: i32
}

impl Iterator for ExtremeIterator {
    type Item = i32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<i32> {
        let result = self.number;
        self.number += 1;
        Some(result)
    }
}

impl DoubleEndedIterator for ExtremeIterator {
    fn next_back(&mut self) -> Option<i32> {
        let result = self.number;
        self.number -= 1;
        Some(result)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let iter = ExtremeIterator { number: 10 };

    for i in iter.rev().take(5) {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

So here's my questions: is there anything semantically wrong with using `DoubleEndedIterator` this way? Is there some reason why it would be a bad idea to use it for a purpose that is different from what the documentation says it is for? Also, is there a better way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, let's clear up this passing remark in your question:

> For example, (1..10) could implement this to be able to go from 1 to 10, or from 10 to 1.

`1..10` is of type [`std::ops::Range<T>`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ops/struct.Range.html) and it iterates to the sequence *1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9* regardless if you iterate it from the back or the front. From the back, you get *9, 8, ...*, from the front you get, *1, 2, ...*; it is a start inclusive, end exclusive range, also called a **half-open** range.

If you would iterate the range a bit from the front and then from the back, it will stop where the ends meet:

```
let mut range = 1..10;

for i in &mut range {
    // Produce 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
    // then break.
    if i == 5 { break; }
}

for j in range.rev() {
    // Produces 9, 8, 7, 6
}
```

And that shows what a well behaved double ended iterator is like. [(rust playpen link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=904305095674c2771470&version=stable)

---

Now, for the question of `DoubleEndedIterator` “abuse”:

It is problematic.

The [DoubleEndedIterator documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.DoubleEndedIterator.html) is clear:

> A range iterator able to yield elements from both ends
>
> A `DoubleEndedIterator` can be thought of as a deque in that `next()` and `next_back()` **exhaust elements from the same range, and do not work independently of each other.**

You must understand this as: Regardless if using `next`, `next_back`, or combinations of these, any traversal must produce the same range of elements if you keep track of them (and keep track of which end they came from).

However, there is the case of infinite ranges...

In an infinitely long range, the ends never meet. An example of such an iterator is [`repeat`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/fn.repeat.html). For this trivial example it's easy to both see why the iterator is infinite, and how both `next()` and `next_back()` are logically defined.

So this is a loophole where you could specify the iterator's sequence as infinitely long, although double ended. I think it is questionable to try to fulfill this interface correctly with our fixed bit width integers.

Even with the dubious philosophical motivation, it might be a very confusing iterator that defies reasonable expectations. I think it would be horrible to use the trait wrong (say having two completely disagreeing ends of an iterator), but with an inexhaustible range you won't actually break any trait properties.

Comment: Thanks.. I hadn't considered that it would be possible to use both the forwards and reverse form of the same iterator.

Comment: Now you know what a double ended range is!